# Configuring MAMP Localhost to Send Emails

Tags: php, email, smtp, localhost, mamp-pro

**Background**

I have MAMP Pro running on my localhost. I have followed a few blogs to set up my localhost server to send emails but one thing does not make sense to me and is never explained.

In each example it says to add my host for sending out emails.

> Host: Fill in your server name for outgoing emails. This could be for
>   instance "smtp.johndoe.com" (without quotes). Ask your provider if you
>   are unsure about the server name.

But I am using MAMP Pro on a localhost. So I would assume this would be localhost.

**Question**

What is the proper way to configure my localhost to be able to send emails.

**What I Have Done**

I opened the php7.0.1 directory which is the version of PHP my MAMP Pro is running right now. I opened the php.ini file and edited the

```
[mail function]
```

section. This is what it currently looks like,

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; SMTP = localhost
; smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path =/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f  dev@localhost.com
```

I am assuming the reason it is still not working is this,

```
dev@localhost.com
```